# PCLStorage problems with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, storage

I've written my application in Xamarin, tested first for Android and later for iOS. On Android all works fine, not in iOS. My problem is related to `PCLStorage`, that fails when read the content of file because `GetFileAsync` result is `null`, but not `CheckExistsAsync` result.

My code is:

```
public static async Task loadMyFile(Func<bool, Task> result) {
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync("myfile.txt").ContinueWith(async (checkExistsTask) => {
        if (checkExistsTask.Result == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists) {
            await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.txt").ContinueWith(async (getFileTask) => {
                try
                {
                    await getFileTask.Result.ReadAllTextAsync().ContinueWith(async (readTextTask) => {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readTextTask.Result))
                            {
                                doWork(readTextTask.Result);
                                await result(true);
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await result(false);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            await result(false);
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await result(false);
                    return;
                }
            });
        } else {
            await result(false);
            return;                 
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using `ContinueWith` here when you are awaiting your Tasks anyways.

I would probably write the code more like this:

```
public static async Task loadMyFile(Func<bool, Task> result) 
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    var exists = await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync("myfile.txt");
    if (exists == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists) 
    {
        var file = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.txt");
        try
        {
            var text = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                doWork(text);
                await result(true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                await result(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await result(false);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        await result(false);
        return;                 
    }
}
```

This reads much more easily, and you get rid of an unnecessary try/catch.

You may want to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your Tasks, so you do not do so much context switching.

You could simplify your method a lot by getting rid of the callback and just return a bool as a result of your Task:

```
public static async Task<bool> loadMyFile() 
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    var exists = await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync("myfile.txt");
    if (exists == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists) 
    {
        var file = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.txt");
        try
        {
            var text = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                doWork(text);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are RIGHT. Now with no ContinueWith works perfectly :) thanks

Comment: For the callback it is important for me for another reasons...thanks a lot